# Looping through directories and printing the files and contents of subdirecotries

Tags: c, windows, while-loop, directory

Note: Can't use dirent.h library.

I need to modify my program to print files and subdirectories in  a directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For example this is what the output should look like:

```
<DIR> U:\Test\
   sample (2).txt   6
   sample.txt   6

<DIR> U:\Test\New folder (5)\
   sample (4).txt   6
   sample (3).txt   6
   sample (2).txt   6
   sample.txt   6

<DIR> U:\Test\New folder (4)\
   sample (5).txt   6
   sample (4).txt   6
   sample (3).txt   6
   sample (2).txt   6
   sample.txt   6

<DIR> U:\Test\New folder (3)\
   sample.txt   6

<DIR> U:\Test\New folder (2)\
   sample (4).txt   6
   sample (3).txt   6
   sample (2).txt   6
   sample.txt   6

<DIR> U:\Test\New folder\
   sample - Copy (2).txt   6
   sample - Copy.txt   6
   sample.txt   6
```

This is what I have so far which only lists the files and subdirectories. I need to able to open the subdirectories and print the associated files. I'm trying to search and print files in seperate functions.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE          hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    size_t          lengthOfArg;
    TCHAR           szDir[MAX_PATH];
    LARGE_INTEGER   fileSize;
    DWORD           dwError;
    FILE            *fp;


do
    {
        // did we find a directory?
        // ffd.dwFileAttributes says this is a directory (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)


            _tprintf(_T("%s  <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);

        // did we find a file?
        else
        {
            fileSize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
            fileSize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
            _tprintf(_T("%s   %ld\n"), ffd.cFileName, fileSize.QuadPart);
        }

        // continue the search; try to find more files
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

Note: Can't use dirent.h library.

Comment: Create and post a _function_ that prints the contents of 1 directory.  Get that working first.

Comment: I thought my code snippet currently does that? can you elaborate please or provide an example?

Comment: As I saw no function header, name, arguments and return value, the post looks like the body of some code and not a function.

Comment: You need to start with a call to FindFirstFile outside the loop.